# Error "SyntaxError: name 'subFrameName' is parameter and global"

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was tweaking my code so I could include scroll bars and this popped up. I have no idea what is wrong here, and I am fairly new to programming.
Here is the function

```
def frameMaker(mainFrameName, canvasName, subFrameName):
    global subFrameName
    mainFrameName = Frame(root)
    mainFrameName.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
    #eee
    canvasName = Canvas(mainFrameName)
    canvasName.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    scrollBar = Scrollbar(mainFrameName, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvasName.yview)
    scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    canvasName.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollBar.set)
    canvasName.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasName.configure(scrollregion = canvasName.bbox("all")))
    subFrameName = Frame(canvasName)
    canvasName.create_window((0,0), window=subFrameName, anchor='nw')
    return subFrameName
    return mainFrameName
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is because you have a naming collision - you have `subFrameName` passed to the function, and then you are declaring `global subFrameName`.

How is the program supposed to work out which version to use? The parameter or the newly declared one? You need to pick one or the other, depending on the rest of your program.

Also, you can't have two return statements (without a conditional). `return mainFrameName` will never be called.

If you were to `return` two variables at the same time, it should take the form `return subFrameName, mainFrameName`. But if you are using `global subFrameName`, you don't need to return a global variable.